# Check for color during widget test?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

The goal is to verify the color of a `RaisedButton.icon`

During my widget tests, I have the ability to look for text with `find.text` as well as icons with `find.byIcon`. There is no built in method for finding color.

How does one do the equivalent of `find.color`?

And example of my code is

```
RaisedButton.icon(
        color: Color(_isAttendingEvent ? 0xFFD9FFB3 : 0xFFE3FFC7),
        icon: Icon(_isAttendingEvent ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border),
        label: Text(
          _isAttendingEvent ? 'Attending' : 'Attend',
        ),
      ),
```

I'm trying to determine whether there is `color: Color(0xFFD9FFB3)` or `color: Color(0xFFE3FFC7)`

And I'm not sure if this is possible

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am not sure with `RaisedButton.icon`, but if it is just an icon you can try using:

```
expect((tester.firstWidget(find.byType(Icon)) as Icon).color, Color(0xFFE3FFC7));
```

If it not the first icon widget that appears on your screen, you can specific an index of it by:

```
expect((tester.widget(find.byType(Icon).at(/*index*/)) as Icon).color, Color(0xFFE3FFC7));
```

### Note: To find a widget colour, you need to cast that widget to be something that contain a color property

For example:

To find Material color you can use:

```
expect((tester.firstWidget(find.byType(Material)) as Material).color, Colors.black);
```

To find Container with BoxDecoration color:

```
expect(((tester.firstWidget(find.byType(Container)) as Container).decoration 
as BoxDecoration).color, Colors.black);
```

To find Text color:

```
expect(((tester.firstWidget(find.text('text')) as Text).style).color, Colors.black);
```

Answer (score 5):

To find Appbar Material. color

```
 final appbar = tester.widget<AppBar>(find.byKey(Key("appbar")));
 expect(appbar.backgroundColor,Colors.white);
```

To find Text color Material

```
final text = tester.widget<Text>(find.text("text"));
  expect(text.style.color, Colors.grey);
  expect(text.style.fontSize, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update you flutter version. It's working now, i am able to access color in widget test. My current flutter version is "Flutter 1.15.18 • channel dev".

Earlier it was not working with version "Flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.5"

Hope this will help. More details [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40295)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a TextButton, ElevatedButton, or Outlined button, the background color will be a MaterialStateProperty. You can verify the color in almost the same way as mentioned above:

```
expect(
        tester.widget(textButton.first),
        isA<TextButton>().having(
          (w) => w.style?.backgroundColor?.resolve({}),
          'button color',
          Colors.grey,
        ));
```